# Count mismatching while using dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I am writing a code in python to count how many of which type error codes are occurred in the file

My file :

```
Tue Sep 01 23:50:17 2015|132491151|959796398631|95931002712|Tue Sep  1 23:50:17 2015|Tue Sep  1 23:50:17 2015|CMT|Undelivered|none|Submit|0|SMSC_no_error|SMPP|ESMEGW|16 Bit|39|78|no||no|no||None|No|NO|no|no|0|0|0|0||||0|0||0|no|no|default_billing|-1|0|no|no|1|1|0|0|1|1|0|0||78456|ussdt|78456|Wed Sep 02 23:50:17 2015|SR|mptcdma2_r|87690|IN|012463814411280170009|||0|1541843||0|0||0|||||||||||||||||||||0|
```

But I am not getting proper output. Where I am missing. Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import xlsxwriter
import subprocess
import pprint
from addict import Dict

data = Dict()

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    date = sys.argv[1]
    print date
else:
    date = subprocess.check_output("date --date='01 hour ago' +%y%m%d%H",shell=True)
    date=date.rstrip()
    print date

input_dir = "/root/prac/Harini/CDR/"
result_dir = "/root/prac/Harini"

year  = "20"+date[0:2]
month = date[2:4]
day   = date[4:6]
hour  = date[6:8]

db_date = year+"-"+month+"-"+day
array = ();
files = ();

try:
    files = subprocess.check_output("ls " + input_dir + "SMSCDR_POSTPAID_" + date + "*.log", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
    array = files.splitlines()
except:
    print "No files in the directory"


for single in array:
    fp=open(single,"r")
    string = fp.readlines();
    for line in string:
        array = line.split('|')
        exp = array[7]
        system_id = array[55]
        last_failure = array[11]
        assign_short_code = array[54];
        if  (exp == "Expired" or exp == "Undelivered"):
            data.db_date.hour.system_id.assign_short_code.last_failure = data[db_date][hour][system_id][assign_short_code].setdefault(last_failure, 0)+1;




pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
{   '2016-04-08': {   '11': {   'ussdt': {   '78456': {   'SMSC_no_error': 0}}}},
    'db_date': {   'hour': {   'system_id': {   'assign_short_code': {   'last_failure': 1}}}}}
```

Expected output

```
{   '2016-04-08': {   '11': {   'ussdt': {   '78456': {   'SMSC_no_error': 1}}}},
```

Comment: Hey could you print the input that you use when getting the provided output?

Comment: Also if you could install and run `tree` and post the file hierarchy that would be great!

Comment: As you suggested I printed the data(print line). Its printing only one line. Is it the correct way to increment the dictionary like that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that `db_date` key because you're adding it:

```
data.db_date.hour.system_id.assign_short_code.last_failure = data[db_date][hour][system_id][assign_short_code].setdefault(last_failure, 0)+1;
#    ^^^^^^^
```

You are using [addict](https://github.com/mewwts/addict). In standard dict notation, that line is equivalent to this:

```
data['db_date']['hour']['system_id']['assign_short_code']['last_failure'] = data[db_date][hour][system_id][assign_short_code].setdefault(last_failure, 0)+1;
#    ^^^^^^^^^
```

I think you meant to write this:

```
data[db_date][hour][system_id][assign_short_code][last_failure] = data[db_date][hour][system_id][assign_short_code].setdefault(last_failure, 0) + 1
```

That is, you want to use the *value of* `db_date` (and other variables), not the literal string `'db_value'`.

Comment: https://github.com/mewwts/addict           

In this I have seen that the assignment is in dots (.)

Comment: @RaviShankerReddy: updated answer. Is it better now?

Comment: Its working very fine now. Thanks for giving clarification on addict

Comment: Because `data.db_date` is equivalent to `data['db_date']`. Look at the example: `my_new_shiny_dict.a.b.c.d.e = 2` becomes `{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {'e': 2}}}}}` -- you have a string `'a'`, not the value of the variable `a`

Comment: I dont know its the right place to ask this. If I read a file like I written in the above code its will load the entire file into memory or not. Is there any better way to read files

Comment: @RaviShankerReddy: change `string = fp.readlines(); for line in string:` to `for line in fp:`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
data.db_date.hour.system_id.assign_short_code.last_failure = data[db_date][hour][system_id][assign_short_code].setdefault(last_failure, 0)+1;
```

should be

```
data[db_date][hour][system_id][assign_short_code].setdefault(last_failure, 0)
data[db_date][hour][system_id][assign_short_code] = data[db_date][hour][system_id][assign_short_code] + 1
```

Note: in python no semicolons